# PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: mlio-py 0.2.7

Tags: python, installation, scikit-learn, conda, mlio

I am trying to install `sagemaker-scikit-learn-container`, in the pypi [page](https://pypi.org/project/sagemaker-scikit-learn-extension/) they write:

> `conda install -c mlio -c conda-forge mlio-py==0.2.7`

however when I try it I get:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - mlio-py==0.2.7
```

Comment: That commands works fine for me, what platform/OS are you using?

Comment: I am on Windows, might it be Linux exclusive?

Comment: That seems to be the issue, looking at the [package on anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/mlio/mlio-py), there is no Windows build listed.

Comment: Did you manage in the end? I had the same problem, I managed to install it on Linux. But now when I try to use it I still get some errors with mlio.

Comment: @BorutFlis `sagemaker-scikit-learn-extension` is a bit of versioning hell, which version of mlio and the extension did you try to install ?

Comment: I have 0.3.1. version of mlio and 2.1.0 version of sagemaker-scikit-learn-extension. What do you mean by versioning hell? I got it to run somehow, but I changed some variable assignment inside the mlio library, I am not sure I should have even done that, but it works for now.

Comment: @BorutFlis I am running `mlio-py=0.2.7` and `sagemaker-scikit-learn-extension == 2.1.0`, No need for a Hotfix.

Comment: I will attempt 0.2.7, but to be honest I think I had some errors with the use of sklearn encoders as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the single equals sign in Conda:

`conda install -c mlio -c conda-forge mlio-py=0.2.7`

I'm not saying there's not going to be any other problem with that install - mlio is very finicky about its dependencies, but the particular error you showed is caused by this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).